# Set instagram account private python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, instagram

For some reason I am having trouble setting my account to private with a simple http request. I am able to edit profile fine, but when I send the request to set my account private, it gives me a 200 status code, along with a successful response message, but when checking my profile, the account is not private...

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

class IGWebAPI:

    def __init__(self, username, password, user_agent):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.user_agent = user_agent
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.session.headers = {'user-agent': self.user_agent}
        self.session.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/')
        self.session.headers.update({'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/', 'x-csrftoken': self.session.cookies['csrftoken']})
        self.session.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', data={'username': self.username, 'password': self.password, 'queryParams' : r'{}'}, allow_redirects=True)
        self.session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.session.cookies['csrftoken']})

    def make_profile_private(self):
        self.session.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/privacy_and_security/')
        self.session.headers.update(
            {'Referer' :'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/privacy_and_security/'})
        a = self.session.post(
                'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/set_private/',
                data = {
                    'is_private' : True
                }
            )
        print(a.text)

username = ''
password = ''
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1'
api = IGWebAPI(username, password, user_agent)
api.make_profile_private()
```

EDIT: Had to add a line to update the headers with the csrf token.

Comment: It looks like Instagram deprecated a lot of their API back in 2018... I couldn't find documentation for the `accounts/` endpoints anywhere. Where did you find that endpoint?

Comment: @Alex I inspected the network traffic via chrome tools.

Comment: I tried running this and I'm getting 403 forbidden error. I'm not sure you are allowed to hit this endpoint from an external origin. Otherwise you may need to include the cookie that is apparently being sent in the request as well.

Comment: @Alex I initially copied this code from another class, just copying what I needed for this post... Forgot a line and had to fix it. Give it another go. Now when I send the request to make my account private the response is `200` with the message `{"status": "ok"}`